# Multiple viewmodels using 1 model?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have viewmodel1 and viewmodel2.

Viewmodel1 needs to show data from a list of some sort contained in model.
Viewmodel2 needs to input data to the list contained in model.

So both Viewmodel1 and Viewmodel2 need to "know" about model.

What is the proper way to do this in MVVM?

Should I create model in app and give viewmodel1 and viewmodel2 a reference to it or?

Comment: can you show some code what you model looks like?

Comment: I have not begon making my code yet. For example:
The Model object contains a list with persons.
Viewmodel1 just shows this list on the view.
Viewmodel2 inserts a new person to the list.
Both these viewmodels therefore need to have a connection to the Model object

Comment: so both viewmodels are on a single view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find it helps if I think of a ViewModel as being a Model, translated just for the View.

You have a few choices:

- Create a *controller* which sets up the ViewModel. This is usually a good choice if the ViewModel needs information from more than one place. You can either give the ViewModel a reference to all the information it needs, or make it a Plain Old .NET Object (PONO) and have the controller set it up for you.
- Just pass the reference to the ViewModel as you suggest. Useful if no interaction is required between different classes
- Wire up the [EventAggregator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921122%28v=pandp.20%29.aspx), which can be used to publish a notification when models change, and pass a [Repository](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html) to the ViewModels so that each of them can go and get / store the model when they need to.

I really like the last pattern as it's easily scalable if you find you need more presenters or controllers with access to these kinds of models. It also lets you inject a repository, which means you can more easily move to a nice RESTful service-oriented architecture later.

If you haven't done much dependency injection before then please consider doing it through the constructor. This will help you avoid situations where things are trying to use your ViewModels before they're ready, and lets the ViewModels do their own work. You might also want to look at frameworks like [Unity](http://unity.codeplex.com/) or [Castle Windsor](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.MainPage.ashx) which can help you do this kind of wiring, but that's really only for big Enterprise projects (and not even all of them).

Answer (score 3):

That's perfectly fine. `Models` are meant to be just what they sound like: data models. They're meant to be dummy objects that hold data, which the rest of the application can use as needed.

`ViewModels` are models that reflect the View. For example, suppose you had a `LoginViewModel` and an `ManageUsersViewModel`. Both ViewModels would work with the `UserModel` data object, however they are entirely different ViewModels for entirely different things.

In most cases, I would leave the responsibility of loading `Models` up to the `ViewModel`. For example, you normally wouldn't pre-load the Users list prior to the User logging in so you'd have their User object available. Insetad,  your `LoginViewModel` would make it's own database call to get the User model of the user logging in, while the `ManagerUsersViewModel` would make its own database call to get the list of users that can be modified.

Comment: I have no experience with C#. But even so I've always been taught that the right place for business logic is in the model. Let alone database calls, which are always a duty of the model.

Answer (score 0):

You must be thinking in a wrong way.. in MVVM your model are contained in ViewModels all the way to the views.. lets say if there is a ObservableCollection then there will be a property in you viewmodel for this and you should be initializing this collection in constructor/some method of the ViewModel.. both viewmodels will initialize ProductTypes like this.. In my opinion you should try create  Classed For Model,ViewModel,Repository and use IoC in it..

here is a really good video on mvvm you should try this video and have a look at the code as well.

http://blog.lab49.com/archives/2650

If the List you mentioned is something that will never change you should try creating a singleton ViewModel for this and reference that viewmodel in other viewmodels.

Regards.